# Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.GetThread. while using getMessages() in GmailThread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I'm trying to get all the messages in a thread in sent items. In the code below, I can get all the sent threads in variable 'mails' as **[GmailThread GmailThread ..]**. Also mails[0].getId() gives threadId of mails[0].

```
var mails = GmailApp.search('in:sent');
Logger.log(mails[0].getMessages());
```

But mails[0].getMessages() returns run time error as

```
Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.GetThread.
```

Here's the scopes I've included.

```
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
"https://mail.google.com/"
]
```

Now what I want is to get all the messages in mails[0].

Comment: May be the user denied permission?

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) at the api document it appears you might be missing the below:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error with Apps Script GMail libraries. I switched to use GMail API sevices instead. Try using them https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/ i didn't face any issues with that.

Comment: I tried to use the Gmail API services. It showed this error "URL has not been whitelisted in the script manifest." But this url is different for each message as it also contains messageId. Is there a way I can dynamically add the messageId to this url so that it is always whitelisted?

Comment: Don't use URLFetchApp for querying APIs, instead use JS library few sample are available here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail check it.